# How to change href value using jquery after page load?

Tags: jquery, href

Below is the html after page load.

```
<div style="width: 960px;">
<a href="Alerts.htm" target="_blank">TEST 1</a>
<a href="blog.htm" target="_blank">TEST 2</a>
<a href="severe.htm" target="_blank">TEST 3</a>
</div>
```

I need to change the href value of  `<a href="blog.htm" target="_blank">TEST 2</a>` after page load using jquery.

I've tried the below options. But it didn't work. Any suggestions/ideas plz...

**TRY I**

```
$(a).attr("href", "http://the.new.url");
```

**TRY II**

```
$('a[href*="blog.htm"]').attr('href', function(i,href) {
    return href.replace('blog.htm', 'http://catbloguat.myblog.com');
});
```

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: you need to wrap your code inside ready function....

Comment: `TRY II` works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/bcRP9/

Comment: Try I missing quotes around 'a' => $('a').attr("href", "http://the.new.url");    [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A6Grg/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`you missed the document ready function`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('a[href*="blog.htm"]').attr('href' , 'http://catbloguat.myblog.com');

});
```

[***Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/6PC99/)

Answer (score 2):

what you have should work (*TryII*)

probably you are not wrapping your code in document ready handler

```
$(function(){
  $('a[href*="blog.htm"]').attr('href', function(i,href) {
    return href.replace('blog.htm', 'http://catbloguat.myblog.com');
  });
});
```

Demo `-->`http://jsfiddle.net/qfQ8W/

Answer (score 1):

You need  to wrap in document ready function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*="blog.htm"]').attr('href', 'http://catbloguat.myblog.com');   
});
```

Example : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2rQzN/)